# Need of verb to complete the sentence

Tags: word-request

I am looking for some word, verb actually, to complete this sentence  -

> My stomach, still heavy from late afternoon lunch was *_*_

In the blank I need some verb that will idiomatically say that my stomach is unwilling to take any food to the point of being thrown up.

Comment: Perhaps overloaded?

Answer (score 1):

I would use replete.

> My stomach, still heavy from late afternoon lunch was replete.

This implies full to capacity.

Comment: +1 a good choice of word. Though I found that it has to do more with *full satisfaction with food* but it also means what OP is asking.

Comment: This is possible but not idiomatic.  *Replete with* is only slightly uncommon, but without *with* the word is not common at all.

Answer (score 1):

here's a few options of some actual verbs and some extra phrases with verbs:

heaving / churning / turning somersaults / rebelling / twisting (itself) in knots

but my personal recommendation would be very similar to Vic:

protesting vigorously

I agree with Bob that 'heavy' is not quite appropriate, but for a different reason - it can be correctly applied to describe the state of your stomach, but it actually has the connotation of it being settled rather than unsettled, I would advise replacing it with one of Bob's suggestions, or the word 'engorged'

Answer (score 0):

Heavy isn't the most typical word we would use.  It isn't most usual to refer to one's stomach directly, either.  So, one approach would be to reword the whole thing:

> I was still so full from the late afternoon lunch that I couldn't eat another bite.

That's a more idiomatic representation of your idea.  However, yours isn't wrong, just a bit formal, or perhaps clinical might be a better word.  We have a tendency to avoid talking about our internal organs when it isn't necessary to describe the situation.

Nevertheless, I would still abandon my quest for another another adjective (you will notice I didn't say verb) if I were you.  You have already said what you want to say with just one.  So you could also do this:

> My stomach was still heavy (full, overloaded, overfull) from the late afternoon lunch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something very English in nature you could try 'full to bursting' as your idiomatic phrase. There are probably better, but that'll do the job.

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple way:

My stomach, still heavy from late afternoon lunch was protesting against the idea of accepting/ or receiving any more food. 
 Not bad, isn't it!

Comment: It is, to be honest. It sounds incredibly non-english!

Answer (score 0):

Today I was revisiting this question and I came up with another suggestion. Since I don't want to remove my first answer, here's my new suggestion:

> My stomach, still full after a late afternoon lunch, was **bloated**.

Admittedly, *"a bloated stomach* does not mean a stomach unwilling to take any food, but it could be argued that in this context it implies so.

Answer (score -1):

If what you really want is a verb, here's another suggestion

> My stomach, still full from the late afternoon lunch, was about to burst.

Comment: why the downvote? Is this sentence incorrect?

Comment: It seems fine to me.  It's possible someone downvoted because the phrase "about to burst" isn't a verb.  I upvoted, though, because the OP is looking for the idiomatic way to express the idea, and because single word requests are off-topic here anyway.

Comment: @snailplane, isn't "to be about to" a modal verb, and "burst" a lexical verb? For example: is the bubble about to burst?

Comment: That's four words; a verb is one.  In that string, *be* is the verb.  Quirk et al. do refer to "be about to" as a quasi-auxiliary in that it functions like one, but morphologically speaking it's clearly a multi-word construction: *be* inflects and you can put multi-word adverbial phrases into the middle of it ("he is actually finally about to"), something you can't do with any single word.  And as in your example, the words can be separated by SAI.